# Converting Python win32evtlog objects to xml

Tags: python, xml, pywin32

I have a app that uses win32evtlog to get and display different events and I would like to limit the display to events of a specific level but win32evtlog doesn't return this.  It seems that you can convert an event to XML and then pull this info but I can't work out how you get the event from a loop to XML.

I can get up to the following and use it to display data the LogObject has such as LogObject.TimeGenerated

```
Log = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog('localhost', 'Application')
while 1:
    LogObjects = winev32tlog.ReadEventLog(Log, win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|wine32vtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ, 0)
    if not LogObjects:
        break
    for LogObject in LogObjects:
```

I tried the convert using

```
LogObjectXML = win32evtlog.EvtRender(LogObject, 1)
```

This unfortunately returns

```
TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object
```

So I know I need to get some sort of handle object that I can use to point the EvtRender at the correct event but can't work out how I do that.

This question is quite similar to [How retrieve from Python win32evtlog rest of info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862430/how-retrieve-from-python-win32evtlog-rest-of-info#) but the solution there didn't answer the critical bit of how we convert the object to XML.

--== Edited with information about the XML for CristiFati ==--

Below is an example of an Application event where the event message reads:-

```
Updated Windows Defender status successfully to SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON.
```

The XML as per event viewer is as below

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="SecurityCenter" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">15</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-05-23T07:36:27.627108000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>49419</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Name.domain.here</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Windows Defender</Data> 
  <Data>SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ReadEventLog* returns *PyEventLogRecord*s (wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: _EVENTLOGRECORD structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_eventlogrecord)), while *EvtRender* expects (you need to work with) *PyHANDLE*s (*PyEVT_HANDLE*s (wrapper over *EVT_HANDLE* ([[MS.Docs]: Windows Event Log Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WES/windows-event-log-data-types)) to be more precise)).
So, for getting *XML* data, you need to use the functions family that works with this type: e.g. *EvtQuery*, *EvtNext*.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pywintypes
import win32evtlog

INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF
EVTLOG_READ_BUF_LEN_MAX = 0x7FFFF


def get_record_data(eventlog_record):
    ret = dict()
    for key in dir(eventlog_record):
        if 'A' < key[0] < 'Z':
            ret[key] = getattr(eventlog_record, key)
    return ret


def get_eventlogs(source_name="Application", buf_size=EVTLOG_READ_BUF_LEN_MAX, backwards=True):
    ret = list()
    evt_log = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(None, source_name)
    read_flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
    if backwards:
        read_flags |= win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ
    else:
        read_flags |= win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ
    offset = 0
    eventlog_records = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(evt_log, read_flags, offset, buf_size)
    while eventlog_records:
        ret.extend(eventlog_records)
        offset += len(eventlog_records)
        eventlog_records = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(evt_log, read_flags, offset, buf_size)
    win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(evt_log)
    return ret


def get_events_xmls(channel_name="Application", events_batch_num=100, backwards=True):
    ret = list()
    flags = win32evtlog.EvtQueryChannelPath
    if backwards:
        flags |= win32evtlog.EvtQueryReverseDirection
    try:
        query_results = win32evtlog.EvtQuery(channel_name, flags, None, None)
    except pywintypes.error as e:
        print(e)
        return ret
    events = win32evtlog.EvtNext(query_results, events_batch_num, INFINITE, 0)
    while events:
        for event in events:
            ret.append(win32evtlog.EvtRender(event, win32evtlog.EvtRenderEventXml))
        events = win32evtlog.EvtNext(query_results, events_batch_num, INFINITE, 0)
    return ret


def main():
    import sys, os
    from collections import OrderedDict
    standard_log_names = ["Application", "System", "Security"]
    source_channel_dict = OrderedDict()

    for item in standard_log_names:
        source_channel_dict[item] = item

    for item in ["Windows Powershell"]: # !!! This works on my machine (96 events)
        source_channel_dict[item] = item

    for source, channel in source_channel_dict.items():
        print(source, channel)
        logs = get_eventlogs(source_name=source)
        xmls = get_events_xmls(channel_name=channel)
        #print("\n", get_record_data(logs[0]))
        #print(xmls[0])
        #print("\n", get_record_data(logs[-1]))
        #print(xmls[-1])
        print(len(logs))
        print(len(xmls))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- The 2 lists should have the same length. The *n*<sup>th</sup> entry in each of them should reference the same event (as long as both functions are called with same value for *backwards* argument (*read below*))
- *get_events_xmls*:

  - Returns a list of *XML* blobs associated to the events
  - The error handling is not the best, you could wrap all *API* calls in `try` / `except` clauses (I didn't run into errors, so I'm not sure what are the situations where exception could be raised)
  - You can play a little bit with [[MS.Docs]: EvtNext function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtnext)'s arguments (*Timeout* and *EventsSize* for performance fine tuning; for me, *~20k* events were processed in a matter of *<10* seconds - out of which text printing and conversions took the most)
  - In *Python 3*, the *XML*s are ***bytes*** ([[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - *class* **bytes**(*[source[, encoding[, errors]]]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)) rather than normal strings (I had to encode them because some contain some non-*ASCII* chars, and attempting to print them would raise *UnicodeEncodeError*)
  - Event filtering is possible, check [[MS.Docs]: EvtQuery function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtquery)'s args (*Flags* and *Query*)
  - Note the *backwards* argument which allows traversing the events in reversed (chronological) order (default set to *True*).
- *get_record_data*:

  - It's just a convenience function, it converts a *PyEventLogRecord* object into a *Python* dictionary
  - The conversion is based on the fact that fields that we care about start with a capital letter (***E***ventID, ***C***omputerName, ***T***imeGenerated, ...), that's why it **shouldn't be used in production**
  - It doesn't convert the actual values (*TimeGenerated*'s value is `pywintypes.datetime(2017, 3, 11, 3, 46, 47)`)
- *get_eventlogs*:

  - Returns a list of *PyEventLogRecord*s
  - As in *get_events_xmls*'s case note the *backwards* argument
  - I must insist on *buf_size*. As [[MS.Docs]: ReadEventLogW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readeventlogw) states, when getting the events, a buffer of max ***512K*** can be used. Now (starting with *PyWin32* version **220**), it's possible to pass it as an argument (the last one) to `win32evtlog.ReadEventLog`. Check **[[SourceForge.hg]: mhammond/pywin32 - Add buffer size parameter for ReadEventLog (patch #143 from cristi fati)](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/rev/955b7db466fe)** for more details. By default, there was a limitation so that the buffer size was hardcoded to *1K*. Since every *ReadEventLog* was accessing the disk, with the new buffer size I got a *10X* speed improvement (for *~180K* events)
- Since I'm storing all the data in the 2 lists (instead of inplace data processing), I am choosing speed over memory consumption. For *~20K* events, the 2 lists are taking *~30MB* of *RAM* (which nowadays I think it's decent enough)

***@EDIT0***: I couldn't find a way to get all the required info with the *Evt** functions family, so I'm getting it from both sources (I enhanced the script that I've previously posted):

***@EDIT1***: According to [[MS.Docs]: OpenEventLogW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openeventlogw):

> If you specify a custom log and it cannot be found, the event logging service opens the **Application** log; however, there will be no associated message or category string file.

[[MS.Docs]: Eventlog Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/EventLog/eventlog-key) lists the 3 **standard** ones. So, that's why it opens the *Application* log. I've done some small changes to the script to test the sources. I don't know where *mmc* gets the *Setup* events from.

Comment: Thanks for that it's really helpful!  When I get the event I also need to be able to display the text that explains what the event is about and I couldn't see a way to get that from the win32evtlog.EvtQuery method.  Is there any way to get these details with this method?

Comment: Isn't all the data included in the _XML_ blob? Is there any piece that's missing? Of course the blob must be parsed in order to get the data out. Here's an example of parsing _XML_: [\[SO\]: Print all xml child node using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699430/print-all-xml-child-node-using-python/42701630#42701630)

Comment: I couldn't fit it into a comment so edited the original with the info from XML and the description I pulled the data from event viewer as it was quicker to give the example than with python.  As you can see the XML doesn't contain the "Friendly" description.

Comment: Did you have the chance to test?

Comment: Aww man I missed the last edit, I still have this script sitting around as a look at again when I have time so will come back to it and test things soon.  Thanks for the time and effort with this!

Comment: Let me know how it turns out :)

Comment: Accepted as this is definitely working.  I do have an issue with the get_eventlogs returning more values for the "Setup" log than get_events_xmls but I suspect this is an issue with win32evtlog.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I wonder why the funcs return different sets of results.... After all they're both reading from the same file. Is there a big difference? Is there a pattern (one situation that I think of is that there are a lot of events logged, and since the `get_eventlogs` call till the `get_events_xmls` one there are events written which are obviously not caught by the 1st call; but there should be very few of them). Is this reproducible by other event types (changing `source_name` __and__ `channel_name`)? I didn't encounter this behavior on my laptop (_Win10_).

Comment: I did a little more poking and it seems like

`def get_eventlogs(source_name="Setup", buf_size=EVTLOG_READ_BUF_LEN_MAX, backwards=True):`

Returns the results for the application log, changing channel_name to setup for the xml's however returns the correct results.  Also win10, I haven't noticed this on other logs.