# How to notify a specific windows log event?

Tags: python, windows, wmi, event-log, pywin32

I am working on a program that needs to notify a specific event in windows event log. I do not know the parameters that are needed to be specified in the NotifyChangeEventLog() function.

Below is the code I have been working with:

```
import win32evtlog 

server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'Application' # 'Application' # 'Security'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = 
win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)
print total
notify = win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(hand, 1)
```

I get this error:

> notify = win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(hand, 1)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> notify = win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(hand, 1)
>
> error: (6, 'NotifyChangeEventLog', 'The handle is invalid.')

What are the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You figured out the 1<sup>st</sup> parameter, which is a handle to an open event log.

According to [[MS.Docs]: NotifyChangeEventLog function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-notifychangeeventlog) (that `win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog` wraps):

> <kbd>hEvent</kbd>
>
> A handle to a manual-reset or auto-reset event object. Use the [CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/1f6d946e-c74c-4599-ac3d-b709216a0900) function to create the event object.

So, you need something like this.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import win32evtlog
import win32event
import win32api
import win32con
import msvcrt


def main():
    server = None # "localhost" # name of the target computer to get event logs
    source_type = "System" # "Application" # "Security"
    h_log = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server, source_type)
    flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
    total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(h_log)
    print(total)
    h_evt = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 1, 0, "evt0")
    win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(h_log, h_evt)
    print("Waiting for changes in the '{:s}' event log. Press a key to exit...".format(source_type))
    while not msvcrt.kbhit():
        wait_result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(h_evt, 500)
        if wait_result == win32con.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            print("The '{:s}' event log has been modified".format(source_type))
            # Any processing goes here
        elif wait_result == win32con.WAIT_ABANDONED:
            print("Abandoned")

    win32api.CloseHandle(h_evt)
    win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(h_log)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- For demo purposes, I am using the "*System*" event log because there's a simple way of generating events

  - Go to "*Services*", pick one (preferably one that's not running), and change its "*Startup type*". When clicking "*Apply*", an event will be generated, which in turn will generate output from the script. 
    At the end, don't forget to undo the changes
- For details regarding reading log events, check [[SO]: Converting Python win32evtlog objects to xml (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911616/converting-python-win32evtlog-objects-to-xml/44111253#44111253)

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py27x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051036392>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py27x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> 3430
> Waiting for changes in the 'System' event log. Press a key to exit...
> The 'System' event log has been modified
> The 'System' event log has been modified
> ```